# "DataFrame" object has no attribute 'reshape'

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I want to reshape some data in a CSV file without header but I keep getting this error

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'reshape'
```

This is my script, I want to reshape the data in 2nd column only

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", header=None, usecols=[1])

start = 0
for i in range(0, len(df.index)):
    if (i + 1)%10 == 0:
        result = df.iloc[start:i+1].reshape(2,5)
        start = i + 1
        print result
```

Here is the CSV

```
1,52.1
2,32.2
3,44.6
3,99.1
5,12.3
3,43.2
7,79.4
8,45.5
9,56.3
0,15.4
1,35.7
2,23.7
3,66.7
4,33.8
1,12.9
7,34.8
1,21.6
3,43.7
6,44.2
9,55.8
```

Output should be like this

```
[[  52.1   32.2   44.6   99.1  12.3]
 [  43.2   79.4   45.5   56.3   15.4]]
[[ 35.7  23.7  66.7  33.8  12.9]
 [ 34.8  21.6  43.7  44.2  55.8]]
```

Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: It looks like you a are looking at stacked data, so you may want to look at pandas' pivot method. It works on your data, but cause you index has so many duplicate values it doesn't give the solution you are looing for.

Comment: the left side is not the index. It's actually a data for 1st column. The answer from @Psidom is what I wanted to do. Btw thank you for your suggestion. =)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`pandas.dataframe` doesn't have a built-in `reshape` method, but you can use `.values` to access the underlying numpy array object and call `reshape` on it:

```
start = 0
for i in range(0, len(df.index)):
    if (i + 1)%10 == 0:
        result = df.iloc[start:i+1].values.reshape(2,5)
        start = i + 1
        print result

#[[ 52.1  32.2  44.6  99.1  12.3]
# [ 43.2  79.4  45.5  56.3  15.4]]
#[[ 35.7  23.7  66.7  33.8  12.9]
# [ 34.8  21.6  43.7  44.2  55.8]]
```

Answer (score 5):

Simplest Answer

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", header=None,usecols=[1])
df.values.reshape(-1,5)
    
array([[52.1, 32.2, 44.6, 99.1, 12.3],
       [43.2, 79.4, 45.5, 56.3, 15.4],
       [35.7, 23.7, 66.7, 33.8, 12.9],
       [34.8, 21.6, 43.7, 44.2, 55.8]])
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
df=pd.read_csv('diabetes1.csv')
df.head()
X=df.iloc[:,:-1]
Y=df.iloc[:,-1].values
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
Xnorm = pd.DataFrame(data = scaler.fit_transform(X))
Yshape = pd.DataFrame(data = Y.reshape(-1,1))
Xshape = pd.DataFrame(data=X.reshape(-1,1))
Ynorm = pd.DataFrame(data = scaler.fit_transform(Yshape))
XTrain,XTest,YTrain,YTest=train_test_split(Xnorm,Ynorm,train_size=0.7,random_state=2)
import keras.backend as K
def r2(y_true, y_pred):
    SS_res =  K.sum(K.square(y_true - y_pred)) 
    SS_tot = K.sum(K.square(y_true - K.mean(y_true))) 
    return ( 1 - SS_res/(SS_tot + K.epsilon()) )
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
import numpy as np
model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(Dense(100,activation='relu',input_dim=3))
model1.add(Dense(100,activation='relu'))
model1.add(Dense(1))
np.random.seed(50)
model1.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mean_squared_error',metrics=['mse',r2])
early_stopping_monitor = EarlyStopping(monitor ="val_loss", 
                                        mode ="min", patience = 5, 
                                        restore_best_weights = True)
history=model1.fit(XTrain,YTrain,epochs=5000,
                  batch_size=64,validation_data=(XTest,YTest),
                  callbacks=[early_stopping_monitor]);

from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
y_train_pred = model1.predict(XTrain)
y_test_pred = model1.predict(XTest)
y_pred = model1.predict(Xnorm)
r2_score(YTrain,y_train_pred),r2_score(YTest,y_test_pred),r2_score(Ynorm,y_pred)

from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
mae=mean_absolute_error
mae(YTrain,y_train_pred),mae(YTest,y_test_pred),mae(Ynorm,y_pred)
print(mae(YTrain,y_train_pred),mae(YTest,y_test_pred),mae(Ynorm,y_pred))

from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
mse=mean_squared_error
mse(YTrain,y_train_pred),mse(YTest,y_test_pred),mse(Ynorm,y_pred)
print(mse(YTrain,y_train_pred),mse(YTest,y_test_pred),mse(Ynorm,y_pred))
```

I have this code and want to run it but get this error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'reshape'